# How to import npm packages without TypeScript definition such that IDE still provide intellisense?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webstorm, typescript-typings

I using an npm package which doesn't not have type definition for TypeScript. To be exact, I'm using `react-google-maps` library.

Following their example, I imported the following components from the package:

```
import {GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker} from "react-google-maps";
```

However, TypeScript throws an error during compilation that:

```
error TS2305: Module '"react-google-maps"' has no exported member 'GoogleMapLoader'.
```

So, my quick fix to this is a declaration of the module with its members of type "any":

```
declare module "react-google-maps" {
    export var GoogleMapLoader:any;
}
```

Now, the problem, however, is that my IDE (WebStorm) doesn't give intellisense anymore. `GoogleMapLoader` is not even recognised as a react component, which I believe would have been recognised (at least the methods and properties without the typings) if I was using Babel.

How can I import npm packages without type definitions to be resolved by TypeScript compiler and yet doesn't obstruct IDE from providing intellisense?

Comment: Try, `preferences` -> `languages & frameworks` -> `JavaScript` -> `Libraries` -> `Add`, and add your npm module as a library.

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov I've added the `react-google-map` folder in node_modules to where you mentioned, but I'm still not getting intellisense of the module. Anything else that I might have missed out?

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov Your suggestion has nothing to do with typescript. The compiler doesn't consult the libraries which WebStorm has configured.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to declare what you're using instead of just using `any`.

For example:

```
declare module "react-google-maps" {
    interface GoogleMapLoaderProps {
        ....
    }

    interface GoogleMapLoaderState {
        ....
    }

    class GoogleMapLoader extends React.Component<GoogleMapLoaderProps, GoogleMapLoaderState> { }
}
```

You can start with just what you're using and need the IDE to support, and slowly add things up.
You can check the [Writing Declaration Files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html) for more info on how to do so.

Comment: The `react-google-map` isn't written by me. It's an npm package which I have installed. So, if I wanted to have intellisense for this package in my IDE, I will have to write out the entire definition file for it? Is there a way, without writing every property and method definition, the IDE can still recognise the classes, methods and properties within the package without the types like how it would have if I had used ES5/ES6?

Comment: No, not really. And the IDE isn't the real issue here as the IDE just uses the compiler as service. You need the compiler to understand what's going on, and then the IDE will know as well. Definition files aren't (in most cases) provided by the maker of the libraries, so other people (the users) write the `.d.ts` files and update the different repositories (such as `DefinitelyTyped`). Your options are to use `any` without IDE support or to write one yourself. You don't have to write definitions to the entire lib, just the parts that you need.

Comment: umm... But wouldn't at least I have the basic intellisense I will get if I didn't use Typescript? I mean, if I had used Babel or plain-old ES5 instead, which doesn't have any definition files to begin with, webstorm would have still given me the basic intellisense based on whatever class members, functions/variables written in the package. But with the "any" Typescript definition, it seems as though I have overwritten any recognition of those functions/variables, and I get zero support from the IDE? It's like a "write definitions" or "have no intellisense at all" scenario?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with working with just js in WebStorm, and I've never worked with Babel so I can't really answer that. But with that being said, you added the ambient declarations because you had a ts error which you solved by defining `GoogleMapLoader` as a `var` of type `any` so from then on that's what you'll get..  Because you're using ts you need to get rid of that error, no way around that (that I'm aware).